# Создаю базу в intelljdea h2, идея видит, данные показывает, но на localhost выскакивает ошибка, что база пустая

Tags: java, intellij-idea, h2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: jdbc:h2:file:C:\db\db1]
Создаю in-memory базу h2 jdbc:h2:mem:pizzacloud, все должно работать, но пишет, что пустая.

jdbc:h2:file:C:\db\db1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138694/discussion-on-question-by-aspiredeveloper----intelljdea-h2--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в несовместимости IDE и драйверов H2. Для поддержки обратной совместимости в строку подключения через точку с запятой необходимо добавить параметр
`OLD_INFORMATION_SCHEMA=TRUE`

При таком способе подключения будет доступна `ретроградная` схема с информацией о БД, которая нужна IDE.

Соответственно, строка подключения должна будет выглядеть следующим образом.

```
jdbc:h2:file:C:\db\db1;OLD_INFORMATION_SCHEMA=TRUE
```

Обновите ее в настройках подключения в IDE.

В `application.properties` укажите

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:\\db\\db1;OLD_INFORMATION_SCHEMA=TRUE
```

---

**Ссылки:**

- Зарегистрированный баг с отсутствием поддержки новых версий h2 в идее:
  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15020